# grouping rows with similar words

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-word, microsoft-office

i have multiple docs having huge amount of textual data which i wanted to group by clustering . grouping lines having multiple duplicates like line 23 have two words car and truck and line 197 having car and truck too and i want to group these two lines together because they have two set of duplicates.

```
car truck scooter bike
cat horse duck rat
ship car boat truck
```

is there any way which detects two or more sets of duplucates in rows and group/sort those rows together such that

```
car truck scooter bike
ship car boat truck
cat horse duck rat
```

i am a noob in excel though

Comment: Unfortunately, what you're asking for would take a very long time to do based on the info you provided. If all that text is bundled up into a single cell, then you'll probably have to break it apart, do analysis on that, and then put it back together and sort it. Where did this data come from? You might be able to group it the way you want before you get it in Excel if it lives in SQL Server, for example.

Comment: thanks sir. sorry for late reply. i am trying excel to use for this